# change this code from if, else to Switch case

Tags: java

How to change this using Switch case

```
int marks = 65;

    if (marks < 50){
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
    else if (marks >= 50 && marks < 60){
        System.out.println("D grade");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invald!");
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `if`? You know that `switch` and `if` are not always interchangeable, right?

Comment: You can't use a switch statement, at least not in a sane manner.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `switch` and `case` statements are mainly used for checking a specific value, along with `enum`. For example:

```
enum RobotState {IDLE, ACTIVE, INACTIVE;}

...
switch (curr_state) {
    case IDLE: ...
    case ACTIVE: ...
    case INACTIVE: ...
    default: ...
}
```

In your example, I do not recommend using `switch` and `case` since you need to check if `marks` fall into a range, not if `marks` is a specific value. However, if you must use `switch` and `case` for your example, you can do the following:

```
switch (marks) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    ...
    case 50: System.out.println("fail"); break;
    case 51:
    case 52:
    ...
    case 60: System.out.println("D grade"); break;
    default: System.out.println("Invald!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using switch with numeric values when the range is too broad (as with your example) is not the best way to go. Lets assume we switch marks in your example, we then should make a case for all the possible values that marks can have (0-100 in this case). As you can see, this is much much more work than using simple if-else.

However, if you still wish to do it, here's how you can go about it:

```
 switch (marks)
    {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("fail");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("fail");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("fail");
            break;
        //continue up to case 49
        case 50:
            System.out.println("D grade");
            break;
        case 51:
            System.out.println("D grade");
            break;
        case 52:
            System.out.println("D grade");
            break;
        //continue up to case 60... etc
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to repeat all those print and break statements.